# Disabling a button/ removing <div>...</div> after someone clicks the submit button (removing for everyone)

Tags: javascript, web

1) Is there anyway that I can do something like

onclick= #remove a specific div class/disable the button for the div class# 
using javascript(open to other suggestions and I don't really know about any other options).

Example:

```
<div class="well" id = 73909><b>This is what i'm trying to do</b>
    <br><form name="Cart" method="post" action="/Cart.cfm">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="73909-button" 
                onclick="remove this.div"
                type="submit" value="ADD TO CART">
        </form>
</div>
```

2) Related

is there anyway for me check the response I get from submitting the form(after the button click) and only perform the task in question (1) if it meets certain criteria?

Comment: it's not clear the question...on the onclick event of a button you want to remove a div element? please put some code example of what you want to do even if it's not syntactically correct

Comment: Added an "example" of what i'm trying to do

Comment: If I'm understanding the question properly, I think what you need to do is build some web service that will accept the data in the form, return some value (true/false, I'm guessing related to inventory?) and depending on that response, remove the clicked button. So, you'll be using AJAX to send the information, and handle the response. Also, if you want to prevent others from clicking it, you probably need another service that the page polls so that it kills the button on everyone's view

Comment: Yes, that is almost exactly what I'm trying to do but instead of getting true/false as returns, I'll be redirected to a website and I'll know if its true or false from the url I'm being redirected to.

Comment: Do you have the possibility of writing code on the server, and if so in what language(s)?  (If not then I don't see any way you can make the change appear for all users.)

Comment: Since my site is going to be hosted on a VPS, I'm open to almost every option out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both, you can use javascript to remove a class from an element as well as disable a button.  Here is an example with jquery:

```
var onBtnClick = function(){
  $('#divWithClass').removeClass('classToRemove');
  $('#btnToDisable').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

There are many validation libraries out there, jquery validation being one, that you can use to validate a form for certain criteria.  HTML5 also has many of these built into the form fields as attributes [HTML5 Validation Examples](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/#.UPmelidQUww)

[UPDATE]
If you want to remove it for everybody, you will need to have each client poll, or use websockets to push, the data for constant updates.  If you are using polling, you will need some validation that the cart item still exists to be removed as it could have been removed by someone else seconds earlier.  Depending on your load, and what you are trying to do, this sounds like a good candidate for websockets.

Comment: But doesn't that just removes/disables the button for the current user and not everyone else?

Comment: I just saw the "removes for everybody" in your title.